# a tpm error (7) occurred attempting to read a pcr value in centos

Tags: centos, tpm

I'm getting this error while booting and my computer won't start.

> a tpm error (7) occurred attempting to read a pcr value

I installed CentOS 7 on a z400 workstation computer.
I was working on it and mounted a USB device from terminal and rebooted the computer, then this problem occurred.

Comment: Do you have encrypted disks, and if so how are they encrypted (the point is, are they using a key in the TPM)? Do you rely on secure boot?

Comment: I dont think, cause i installed it almost with defaults. If not is there any way to see it?

Comment: Have this on a Fedora 24 on a Fujitsu D2778-C1 Workstation. It appears in the kernel log, but the machine boots nevertheless.

Comment: I also see this message on a HP probook installed with centos7, but no problem for booting

Answer (score 7):

In case if somebody facing this issue in the boot time , the bellow steps fixes my issue :

first of all I was getting that error Message while booting :

```
a tpm error (7) occurred attempting to read a pcr value
```

and I've fixed it by :

within your grub menu choose

```
Advanced options for ubuntu
```

from the list which will pop up choose the recovery mood :

```
Ubuntu, with linux x.x.x.x (recovery mood)
```

you will boot your system in the recovery mood, which will pop up some errors to you.

one of those errors in checking your file system :

> failure file system check of the root filesystem failed
>   ...
>   The root filesystem on ***/dev/sdaX*** requires a manual fsck

in my case it was /dev/sda2 ,

you need then to run the following command :

```
fsck /dev/sdaX
```

while sdaX is your boot driver.

a lot of prompts will ask you about fixing the issue,

hit yes for all those messages , after you finishing the fix , reboot your system :

```
$ reboot
```

and it should works fine.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with Ubuntu 16.10 on an HP Compaq 6710b - ironically, enabling the TPM in the BIOS fixed the problem. I initially tried disabling it but enabling and allowing the OS to manage it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Disable TPM security from your BIOS settings , boot with `nomodeset`

Then add `blacklist tpm_tis` to your `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

Comment: What is nomodeset, how to boot with nomodeset?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it just booted after 5 seconds and i did nothing to the bios and i'm using Ubuntu 16.04 as my main computer yes my main computer not a virtual machine and it just came out of a menu that showed up when i booted my compuer up it said use the up and down arrows and on the top it said *Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I have not TPM but TCG. It was Inactive (see help message at the picture below) and I chosen Disable because I really don't know what security feature will activate and the message at boot is gone.
[image: Picture: Lenovo-Bios-Setup-Utility: Security tab -> TCG Feature Setup]