# Booting problem - A tpm error (7) occurred attempting to read a pcr value

Tags: linux-mint, boot, tpm

When I try to boot up Linux Mint, it gets stuck at `initramsfs` with the following error messages:

```
[       1.892162] tpm tpm0: A tpm error (7) occurred attempting to read a pcr value

[       2.012154] tpm tpm0: A tpm error (7) occurred attempting to read a pcr value
```

I will additional details as comments, since a seemingly lengthy question may scare away people.

Comment: Potential cause: 
I was close to running out of space for my Linux Mint (only had 1 GB left and Linux warned me about that). When I booted it the next time, it did not allow me to download any files (something about something being read-only). When I tried to boot it the next time, the current problem suddenly was there.

Comment: Also, probably the highest rated solution in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/305719/a-tpm-error-7-occurred-attempting-to-read-a-pcr-value-in-centos would fix the problem. Problem is I couldn’t try it so far, as I get stuck at `loading initial ramdisk` in the recovery mode (I have also erased the `quiet` option as suggested in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/257203/booting-stops-at-loading-initial-ramdisk, but it didn’t fix the problem).